What is the meaning of equation $XX^T + YY^T = I$ for some n by p matrices X and Y?
What is the meaning of sum $XX^T + YY^T = I$ for some n by p matrices X and Y?
I am studying matrix concentration theory, and I have encountered a new definition involving matrix convex combinations.
Let $A_1$ and $A_2$ be Hermitian matrices. Consider a decomposition of the identity of the form
$$K_1^*K_1 + K_2^* K_2 = I$$
Then the Hermitian matrix
$$K_1^*A_1K_1 + K_2^*A_2K_2$$
is called a matrix convex combination of $A_1$ and $A_2$.
I am confused about the meaning of the equation since there are no assumptions that make $K_1^*K_1$ or $K_2^*K_2$ be a projection matrix.
Is there any mathematical or geometric meaning of the equation?

The sum of the Gram matrices of $K_1$ and $K_2$ equals the identity matrix. This can be interpreted as a kind of orthogonality condition where the matrices $K_1$ and $K_2$ are constrained in a way that their combined contributions to the Euclidean space are orthonormal.

One thing to note is that if $K_1$ and $K_2$ are multiples of the identity matrix, then $K_1^*AK_1 + K_2^*A_2K_2$ is a convex combination in the usual sense. In this way, the idea of a "matrix convex combination" is a generalization of the usual notion of a convex combination.

Another observation is that the block-matrix
$$
K = \pmatrix{K_1 \ K_2}
$$
satisfies $K^K = I$, which is to say that $K$ has orthonormal columns. The "matrix convex combination" can be written as
$$
\pmatrix{K_1 \ K_2}^ \pmatrix{A_1 & 0\0 & A_2} \pmatrix{K_1\ K_2} = K^*AK,
$$
which is a compression of $A$, where
$$
A = A_1 \oplus A_2 = \pmatrix{A_1 & 0\0 & A_2}.
$$

@BenGrossmann Thanks. So it is just the generalized version of the convex combination for the matrix.

@someeed That's right, and that's what is being alluded to with the terminology
